# IE not painting elements

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

Okay, here's a doozy of a question. And I would greatly appreciate any ideas or leads to a possible solution.

I have a web application that handles filing electronic documents. So on one of our panels, we have a file tree that we have created (it's essentially nested ul elements). When you click on a "folder", we then reveal the list elements underneath it. Well, some of these lists can be long, so we're using some virtualization of the elements to keep the server strain down.
Well, this is all fine and dandy for every browser... Except IE, the troubled child of web browsers it seams.

This bug is not consistent, but it is reproducible, which makes solving the issue a royal pain. When the user clicks on the folder level, you can see that the ul is toggled to show it's child elements (the side panel resizes appropriately, and our icon to signal an expanded state is changed), however, **visually** no elements are there. You can browse the DOM and see the elements exist, and there is no special CSS classes or styles being applied that would result in the hiding of elements.

The kicker. Any kind of task which repaints the document will result on everything showing up properly. Such events would be resizing the window (or doing anything to the window), hovering over a dom element in the dev tools (which causes a blue hue to be shaded over the selected dom element), and so on. I have tried running in compatibility mode, safe mode (no extensions), and reset IE completely. Again, **this issue is only present in IE**. And it seems to be constrained to painting elements.
To me, it almost sounds like an issue within IE11 with painting elements, as no other browsers are having this issue, and there's no code used that is "special" in the sense that it's not fully supported in all browsers.

### So my question is two part.

1. Has anybody experience issues with IE not painting elements properly?
2. Do you have any leads on what could be causing issues with painting a screen?

#### *Edit: Additional Information*

**Error State:**
[image: No sub folders visible]

**Correct State**
[image]

When you click on the arrow to expand the tree, things get re-sized appropriately to make room, yet everything is invisible. A simple grab of the IE window resizer (or anything else that causes a repaint) will cause the elements to appear correctly (the correction happens instantly). Again, this is only in IE.
The basic structure is:

div
-div
--div
---section
----div
-----ul
------li (folder level headers)
-------ul
--------li (sub folder levels - *not painted*)
---------ul (any other sub folders inside parent folder)

Comment: 1.) its IE the answer should always be yes. xD ||||| 2.) Could you upload it somewhere so we can take a look?

Comment: Yep, I've seen this happening. Wrap the outmost `ul` within an extra `div`, and everything will work just fine.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't upload the actual page due to this being some beta software, and I can't share the page. I'll see if I can't create a shareable fiddle with the same issue. Teemu, I'm going to try it on monday, and will see if it works, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: If the outmost tree-element is a direct child of `body`, this happens when any element within that element is resized/toggled to show, and this resize will cause scrollbar(s) to appear to `body`. Though I'd recall this happened in older IEs (IE<9), and I couldn't reproduce the issue with IE11.

Comment: *See the edits for additional information*. Thanks for the idea Teemu. The tree structure is not a direct child of the body (it is embedded a few more layers deep). And it doesn't appear to be an issue with the scroll bar. All the elements exist in the DOM, they are just **not painted** onto the screen.

Comment: And Teemu, the outmost ul is already wrapped in layers of divs, so I don't think another layer of divs might do anything different.

Comment: Is it only IE11 which exhibits this behavior? a http://codepen.io/ link with the relevant files / JS would be helpful.

Comment: It's happening in IE 10 and IE 11 (can't test it in IE 9). I tried to make a JSFiddle with it, but the problem is we have many plugins and frameworks configured, I can't share all the code due to the nature of the project. We are following the MVVM pattern, and using Knockout as our framework (along with JQuery), if that helps at all. Again, the issue is quite common, but *not reproducible every time*

Comment: I had a slightly similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793526/ie-is-not-painting-elements/33793527#33793527