# IE is not painting elements

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, svg

I have an angular app that is using SVG to draw a horizontal bar chart and a vertical bar chart.

However, the horizontal bar chart is not being painted.  The horizontal SVG rects are in the DOM and will paint correctly if I simply toggle off and back on a CSS property. But they will not paint initially.

Comment: Can you give some code examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my application I was using Angular Material.  Angular Material has the following CSS selector:

```
md-menu-content[width="3"] {
min-width: 168px; }
```

I removed the above CSS and my Horizontal Bar chart paints.

My guess is that IE does not work well with non-native DOM element selectors and that because I was animating on the same width attribute(in my horizontal bar chart) that this selector was querying it broke IE's paint algorithm.